# Weird behaviour of Mailapp.sendEmail in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been sending emails successfully through Google apps script triggered through submission in a Google sheet. Lately (about a week back), the email sender starts behaving very weird.

If I use the following format, my emails get bounced

`MailApp.sendEmail(email1, subject, message,{cc:email2,attachments:[file.next()]});`

If I use the following form, the email does NOT get delivered neither does it get bounced

`MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);`

If I use the following format, the recipient gets the message as shown

`MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,{htmlBody: message});`

Revecied message

`[object Object]`

and the rest of the stuff blank!

I'm at my wits' end as to how to go about. Any help or a pointer will be of immense help. Regards

Madhurjya

Following is the app script, which is attached to the Google sheet. Once I run the function sendPasswd() from sheet, it gets some vital parameters from the sheet data and then send the message to the person (through the variable email2)

```
function sendPasswd() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange()
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var subject = "Example Subject";
  var message = "";
  var i;
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("some_file.pdf");
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (i == 0) continue; // Skip the first row
    if (row[4] == "Sent") continue;
    var first = row[0]; var last = row[1]; var email = row[2];
    var passwd = row[3]; var email2 = row[7];
    if (row[15] == "some condition") {
      message = "Dear <b>"+first+" "+last+"</b>,<br><br>"+
      "This is to inform you that your .... ";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email2, subject, message);
      //MailApp.sendEmail(email2,subject,{htmlBody: "message"});
      //MailApp.sendEmail(email2, subject, message,{cc:"some_email@example.com",attachments:[file.next()]});         
    }
  }
}
```

The surprising fact is that from the same account similar emails are being sent and are NOT affected!

Madhurjya

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: you are receiving this message  [object Object]   is because the message need to convert from object to string.

Comment: try to log your message. comment out the MailApp and see what's the message looks like. If it's object, convert it into string.   Then this will be fixed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior: `MailApp.sendEmail(email2, subject, message);` works correctly, and `MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,{htmlBody: message});` is not a valid method (see vector's answer). Would you consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Is this behavior reproducible in multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening because you're using `htmlbody`  which is part of `options` as third argument whereas in `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` of class `MailApp`, `body` should be third argument, that's is the reason of getting `[object Object]`.

**Try following modification:-**

```
MailApp.sendEmail(email2,subject,"",{htmlBody: message});
```

**Reference:**

[sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this way (its really more practical):

```js
const email 'yourEmail@outlook.com'
const cc ='copyEmail@hotmail.com'
const bcc = 'blindCarbonCopy@gmail.com'

MailApp.sendEmail({
              to:email,
              cc: cc,
              bcc: bcc,
              subject: 'Whatever you want, even template strings' ,
              htmlBody: `

               You could just create your HTML IN HERE (using template strings)
               Or create before and add here as variable as well.
              
              `
            })
```